# Filter Full Text Search based on User ID

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "this test"
    }
  }
}
```

This gave me below result:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "successful" : 6,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.5753642,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "inbox",
        "_type" : "mailbox",
        "_id" : "6bb174ab-a4ce-4409-a626-c9a42c98b89e",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 13,
          "content" : "This is a test"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "inbox",
        "_type" : "mailbox",
        "_id" : "1304cf2e-a1d4-40ca-9876-9abb08c4474d",
        "_score" : 0.36464313,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 10,
          "content" : "This is a test"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "inbox",
        "_type" : "mailbox",
        "_id" : "623c093c-4408-445e-abb1-460d2c5004cd",
        "_score" : 0.36464313,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 15,
          "content" : "This is a test"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which is good. However, I need to filter them by `user_id`. I mean I need to score only specific user and their content.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "this test",
      "user_id": 10
    }
  }
}
```

When I add `user_id` i get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[match] query doesn't support multiple fields, found [content] and [user_id]",
        "line": 5,
        "col": 18
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[match] query doesn't support multiple fields, found [content] and [user_id]",
    "line": 5,
    "col": 18
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Why? And How to properly filter based on `user_id`?

Comment: Add the query giving the error.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that. Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) to filter the result by user_id.

Update your query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "this test"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am stuck at middle with your answer and Val's answer. Both works but gives me different scores. For example, your query gave me 0.36... score however Val's 1.32.... I am wondering which one is the better one.

Comment: If you just want to filter by user_id and want to score only on matching `content` field then use the query in my answer. If you want to consider scoring based on user_id as well along with content the use the query in answer given by @Val

Comment: No. UserID is permanent. Must match as it is. I need to score against content. Thank you very much for explaining this way. Now I understand filter + match better.

Answer (score 1):

The query should be like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "this test"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "user_id": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bool query to combine filters

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "this is content"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": {
              "value": 47545
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```